# how to encrypt file using aws_Sdk

Tags: python, encryption, aws-sdk

file_path = 'upload/abc.tar'

in **source=source_plaintext** I want to give a file but how to do this

if I assign file_path then it will take as a string

```
kms_kwargs = dict(key_ids=[key_arn])
    if botocore_session is not None:

        kms_kwargs['botocore_session'] = botocore_session
    master_key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.KMSMasterKeyProvider(**kms_kwargs)

    # Encrypt the plaintext source data
    ciphertext, encryptor_header = aws_encryption_sdk.encrypt(
        source=source_plaintext,
        key_provider=master_key_provider
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the provided [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python-example-code.html)

If you want to encrypt the file itself, you may check the part *Encrypting and Decrypting Byte Streams*, there you can encrypt whole file (any stream).

The part you are trying is to encrypt a single string. This is used for encypting data encryption key.  Basic idea is that you can generate a random data encryption key, encrypt data using the data key and then encrypt the data key with the master (kms) key.